# React with react-router: render component by replacing content in an element

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, react-router

In my app, I am using React.js as my javascript framework, in combination with react-router for navigation.

I have a problem in replacing the content of my main container div. When I access some new route, the appropriate route handler is activated calling the render method, but that html is appended to the existing content of the main container div, and I need it to be replaced.

Page2Handler only appends its html to the existing html that App handler render on the initial page load.

What am I doing wrong here?

router.jsx:

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var { Route, DefaultRoute, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Link = Router.Link;
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var App = require('./app');
var Page2Handler = require('./pages/Page2Handler');

var MyRoutes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
        <Route name="page2" path="/page2" handler={Page2Handler} />

    </Route>
);

module.exports=MyRoutes;
```

client.jsx:

```
var MyRoutes = require('./router');

Router.run(MyRoutes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById('container'));
});
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=""~/build/client.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Page2Handler:

```
var React = require('react');

var Page2Handler = React.createClass({
mixins: [ Router.State ],
    render: function() {
        return (
              <div>Hello Page2Handler </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports=Page2Handler;
```

App.jsx:

```
    var React = require('react');
    var Router = require('react-router');
    var { Route, DefaultRoute, RouteHandler, Link } = Router;

    var Header = require('./modules/header');
    var Footer = require('./modules/footer');
    var SearchPartners = require('./modules/partners/search-partners')

    var App = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Header />

                    <div id="body">
                    <SearchPartners />
                         <RouteHandler />
                    </div>

                    <Footer />
                </div>
            );
        }
    });

    module.exports=App;
```

Comment: Do the contents of the first <code> tagpair represent the file './router'? It would also be helpful if we could see what the App and Page2Handler files look like.

Comment: Yes, the first part represents the router. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, Page2Handler is being rendered *inside* App - if you look at the structure of your routes, and how you're rendering RouteHandler inside App, it should be fairly easy to see why.

To fix this, you're going to want to have a general parent page, containing, for example, your header and footer, and then have your App and Page2Handler routes on an equal level with a DefaultRoute, like this:

```
<Route name="someparent" path="/" handler={ParentHandler}>
  <DefaultRoute handler={App}>
  <Route name="page2" path="/page2" handler={Page2Handler} />
</Route>
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you, now I understand a little bit better how routing with react-router works.